# Postgres ARRAY column type to tbl list column in R and viceversa

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

Let's say that I'm working with the `starwars` dataset from dplyr package, which contains list columns (for films, vehicles...). To simplify,
let's work with only the name and the films data:

```
library(dplyr)
ex_data <- starwars %>%
  select(name, films)

ex_data

# A tibble: 87 x 2
   name               films    
   <chr>              <list>   
 1 Luke Skywalker     <chr [5]>
 2 C-3PO              <chr [6]>
 3 R2-D2              <chr [7]>
 4 Darth Vader        <chr [4]>
 5 Leia Organa        <chr [5]>
 6 Owen Lars          <chr [3]>
 7 Beru Whitesun lars <chr [3]>
 8 R5-D4              <chr [1]>
 9 Biggs Darklighter  <chr [1]>
10 Obi-Wan Kenobi     <chr [6]>
# ... with 77 more rows
```

And I want to copy this data to a PostgreSQL database, but I want the films column to be converted to an text array type in the SQL, something like this:

```
starwars=# \d test
       Table "public.test"
   Column   |  Type  | Modifiers
------------+--------+-----------
 name       | text   | not null
 films      | text[] |
```

Is there any easy way of doing this with `dplyr` and/or `dbplyr`?

Also I'm interested in the opposite operation, importing a table with an array type column from postgreSQL db into R and getting a list-type column for the array one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Changed tidyverse to dplyr, as the dataset comes with the latter package. Good question! Have you found a solution for that?

Comment: @andschar Thanks for the change ;) Sadly i haven't found the solution yet for this

Answer (score 1):

Below a poor man's workaround using the existing R database packages and some SQL code. I use the **data.table** package for wrangling the data (can easily be adapted to **dplyr**).

```r
# packages
require(data.table)
require(RPostgreSQL)

# data preparation
dt = dplyr::starwars
setDT(dt)
dt = dt[ , .SD, .SDcols = c('name', 'films') ]
# list conversion
dt2 = dt[ , .(films = unlist(films)), name ]

# database I/O
drv = dbDriver('PostgreSQL')
con = dbConnect(drv,
                dbname = dbname,
                user = user, password = password,
                host = host, port = port)
# write
dbWriteTable(con, name = 'test', value = dt2,
             overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
# convert to array in database
q = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;
     CREATE TABLE test2 AS (
       SELECT name, array_agg(films) AS films
       FROM test
       GROUP BY name
     );"
dbSendQuery(con, q)

# read arrays
dt3 = dbReadTable(con, 'test')

# convert back to list columns
setDT(dt3)
dt4 = dt3[ , .(films = list(films)), name ]

dbDisconnect(con)
dbUnloadDriver(drv)
```

**Some thoughts:** It would be nice if such a feature existed in [RPostgreSQL](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL) or one of the other database packages. It surely doesn't scale well. Unfortunately, I lack skills in C to help implementing this.